# Resolving issues regarding installation of PHP::Interpreter module on strawberry perl

Tags: perl, cpan, strawberry-perl

I have been facing this issue while installing PHP::Interpreter on the cpan client of strawverry perl.

---

```
cpan> install PHP::Interpreter
Database was generated on Tue, 02 May 2017 06:44:13 GMT

Running install for module 'PHP::Interpreter'
Checksum for C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\sources\authors\id\A\AF\AFF\PHP-Interpreter-1.0.2.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\build for sizes
............................................................................DONE
Configuring A/AF/AFF/PHP-Interpreter-1.0.2.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
using php_config 'php-config'
'php-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Failed to find the 'php-config' executable. Make sure you have PHP and PHP sources installed, and that 'php-config' is in PATH. at Makefile.PL line 55.
Warning: No success on command[C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL]
  AFF/PHP-Interpreter-1.0.2.tar.gz
  C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL -- NOT OK
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'PHP::Interpreter'.
Failed during this command:
 AFF/PHP-Interpreter-1.0.2.tar.gz             : writemakefile NO 'C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL' returned status 256
```

---

Tried installing it again as well and got similar errors as shown below

---

```
cpan> install PHP::Interpreter
Running install for module 'PHP::Interpreter'
  AFF/PHP-Interpreter-1.0.2.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\build\PHP-Interpreter-1.0.2-1
  AFF/PHP-Interpreter-1.0.2.tar.gz
  'C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL' returned status 256, not re-running

cpan>
```

---

Help me resolving the above issue.

Thanks in advance !!

Regards,
Shreeram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That module is broken. Find an alternative.

It hasn't been updated since 2008, and is no longer compatible with any current version of PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the information . But do you have any other module/s which will help me integrate the codes between PHP (front-end codes) and Perl (back-end codes) ? It would be really great help :-)